# QWidget Translucent Areas do not accept any event

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a simple QLabel inside my Parent Widget and I make my Parent Widget Translucent with attribute
`w.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground , true)` and Window Flag `w.setWindowFlags(Qt::ToolTip | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)`,but after that only Areas that are not Opaque and have pixels in parent widget will accept any event.

is there anyway to overcome this situation ?, I must note that **this code works very well in my Kali Linux**!

Here is the ScreenShot :

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].  Also clarify which event types you are trying to process.

Comment: @G.M. Hi the code is really simple ,in my main, I setup my Translucent background `w.setWindowFlags(Qt::ToolTip | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)`  
and `w.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground , true);` and QLabel with QPixmap loaded in my main widget